# Setting the root for Svelte application

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I am trying to create UI for a desktop application using web technologies. The created app will be rendered by Chromium Embedded Framework, in a desktop window.

I have created a Svelte app and have built it. But in the `bundle.js` file the references to the assets are like `src="/images/Global/Logo_OnDark.svg"`. This works only when we serve the app from a webserver. Since I want this to be rendered from disk, I need the assets to be referenced with relative paths with "dots", like `src="./images/Global/Logo_OnDark.svg"` or `src="../images/Global/Logo_OnDark.svg"` Is there a way to achieve this in the bundler?

With React I was able to achieve this by adding `"homepage": "."` in package.json file, but in Svelte(and rollup), I am unable find a similar solution. any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: In SvelteKit you can in theory configure the `config.kit.paths.base` option, but [it seems to be a bit buggy](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2571). However, from your wording I'm not even sure if you're using SvelteKit or just Svelte.

Comment: Hi @Odilf, I am not using Sveltekit, its just Svelte.